Paired or independent sample T-test
I have a statistical project that am working on that is made up of two groups(control and intervention) and the participants in the two groups are different from each other. Measurement of biomarkers were taken at baseline and endpoint for the intervention group within 12 weeks.i.e, patient P1 in control group body weight was taken at baseline and after 12weeks. Same process for other patients in the intervention group. In the end, there are about 300 variables for 21 participants.
I want to know if there is any difference within and between the two groups. I mean, what is the effect of the intervention within and between groups? Initially, 'GLMM' was proposed, but from the data it did not meet the assumptions of GLMM. I intend to use paired sample t-test, but it seems it is not the right statistical model to apply because I assumed the measurements (data) are independent between groups. I also thought of Linear mixed model(LMM) but am not quite sure looking at the assumptions of LMM. My first approach is to apply PCA/K-means to identify clusters of variables, then use these clusters variables for analysis.
NB: all the data are continuous
I need suggestions/help on the right approach to use for this analysis.
The attached images is the design of the experiment


"paired sample t-test (non-parametric)"?  As far as I know, the t-test is, by definition, parametric....

I mean 'Wilcoxon signed rank test'

Just as a comment: Within-group comparisons are not sensible in an RCT for many reasons: Regression to the mean, the fact that neither group is likely a random sample of any sensible population (so not representative) just to name two. Stephen Senn has written on this. See also this paper.

what do you mean by RCT?

"...and the participants in the two groups are different from each other." In what ways are they different? Just in type of treatment received (control vs. intervention) or in all other characteristics as well?

Different in the sense that, they are not the same persons.

but from the same population of Cadiac Rehabilitation

in all other characteristics

You have 300 variables to test? Do you want to do 300 tests?

300 variables to me is on the high side. I intend to apply PCA/K-means or hierarchical clustering to identify variable similarity. then, I will use these variables within this cluster for the analysis. Just to reduce the dimension. I don't know if it makes sense statistically


You can not perform any paired test (t-test or Wilcoxon signed) because the subjects in your 2 cohorts are different. You have 2 independent samples (control and intervention cohorts), so you will have to use, independent samples tests (e.g. Welch t-test, or Mann-Whitney U, etc.).
You say you have "300 variables"; I assume this means you measured 300 different endpoint measures on the subjects? And you intend to run 300 different tests on these? Obviously you will then have a multiple comparison issue; with such a large number of comparisons, your "family-wise" significance $\alpha$ will be very small (e.g. 0.000167 via Bonferroni, instead of the "traditional" .05). W/o multiple comparison correction (MCC), from 300 tests, you would expect roughly 15 false positive results (i.e. significant differences when in fact there was none), using the "traditional" .05 significance. How do you sort these out? Holm-Sidak, or Hochberg-Sidak may be better MCC's for large number of comparisons, but you still run a high risk of false positives.
You also say that you have 21 subjects? Is that per cohort, or both combined? In both cases, that is a (very?) small sample size for testing with such a low significance (see point #2).
You say you would like to look at within and between group differences. To look at within group differences, you would need to have identified other factors; e.g. gender, or age, or smoking/no smoking, etc. You do not mention any such, so you really can not do any withing group comparisons. Even if you had such additional factors, it will just increase the number of simultaneous comparisons, and reduce the sample size, aggravating the issues mentioned above.
You mention flavors of LMM. But so far you only indicate a single predictor (intervention vs. control). Such a model will not tell you anything more than 2-sample tests. If you have more predictors, you should expand your question to describe them.
For using Welch t-test, you would need to confirm that all 600 datasets (both sets for each of the 300 comparisons) are "normal-ish enough". That will not happen. And 21 is not large enough a sample size to instead rely on the CLT.
You could use a Mann-Whitney U test (MWU). But note that it is not, generally, a test of the medians (as incorrectly described in many sources). It is a test of stochastic superiority (i.e. $P(X>Y)>.5$); see e.g. here on CV, or here on wiki. Using it as a test of the medians requires non-trivial assumptions, which again with 300 comparisons will not hold for many (most?) of them.

So what should you do in the end? I would probably run 300 MWU tests, and look at all the 300 p-values. I would not publish these results (because of the false positive issue). I would then select a much smaller subset of the 300 biomarkers (5, 10?), either because they are the most "interesting" clinically, or because they have the lowest p-values, (or both), and I would run a new study, with just these 5-10 biomarkers, using an appropriate MCC (Sidak?), to confirm that they are not likely to be false positives. And this is what I would publish (i.e. use your current study as a screening study).

in response to No2, the 300 variables are biomarkers measured at both baseline and endpoint.i.e, the same variables measured at baseline were measured at end point. for example Blood pressure, weight, height, Lean body mass, Lipids, diary intake ...etc. I intend to reduce these 300 using PCA/K-Means or hierarchical clustering. the clustered variables I will then use them for the analysis


21 subjects for only one cohort. meaning, I have 42 subjects for both



the other predictors are what I said in response to No2. I proposed to use control/Intervention as Random and the other predictors as fixed effect. But, will the result answer my research question? am not sure about that


from your last paragraph, your suggestion sounds interesting. I was thinking of this approach using MWU: I intend to evaluate the difference in measurement between endpoint and baseline of the biomarkers of the two groups. I will check for MWU assumption and thereafter, I will perform MWU analysis between groups. is there any statistical sense in my approach?
